# How to create ranges per 2 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
+------------+
|    date    |
+------------+
| 2018-07-01 |
| 2018-09-01 |
| 2018-08-01 |
+------------+
```

How do I query in such a way so as to get the following results?

```
+------------+------------+
|  min_date  |  max_date  |
+------------+------------+
| 2001-01-01 | 2018-07-01 |
| 2018-07-01 | 2018-08-01 |
| 2018-08-01 | 2018-09-01 |
+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lag()` takes three arguments with the third argument being the default, so you can write this as:

```
select lag(date, 1, '2001-01-01' as date) over (order by date) as min_date,
       date as max_date
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
select coalesce(lag(date) over(order by date), '2001-01-01'), date 
from t
```